# How to handle cookies on application upgrade?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I am new implementing authentication process. Now I am storing cookies and getting cookies to authenticate.

I am getting the problem when I Upgrade my web application, I would like to delete old cookies when I update application and start with cookie.

How can I catch web application update and delete old cookies?

How can I store username and password securely using cookies?

Comment: `How can I store username and password securely using cookies?` You can't. Store a hashed token in the cookie instead.

Comment: Questions are free: please don't use a single question to ask about entirely different things.

Comment: @AlvaroG.Vicario wow! what a discovery, are they really free? you are amazing. Thanks a lot for your kind info.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting old cookies can be done by settings its expiration date into the past.

Don't store username and password in cookies. If you do, you must verify that data on every request. Store the username in the session once the user ha proven thgat he knows the password that is associated with the username.

Comment: How can I catch application upgrade to delete cookies?

Comment: You cannot delete all old cookies that you have ever set. You have to wait for the client to connnect, check which version of the application has set the cookie and then react appropriately. But I do not know of a valid use case that requires deleting cookies due to application upgrade. Can you give such a use case?